# How to effectively debug a multi-threaded curses client-server application with gdb?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, ncurses

I'm writing a small client/server application that uses `ncurses` as TUI toolkit on the clients. The clients are multithreaded, there is a thread that is used to communicate with the server(via sockets) and a thread that handles the UI. I discovered a bug and I'd like to step through the instructions of the clients to see where the problem lies<sup>1</sup>.

Simply running the clients in `gdb` doesn't work because `gdb` uses the same terminal as the client, hence the output is all messed up and this makes it really hard to read the output of `gdb` and it seems to also interfere with `curses`(e.g. with `halfdelay` mode, when stepping through the instructions I'm not able to send any key press to the client, since every time the programs drops to `gdb` after a small amount of time.)

Is there a way to run `gdb` in a "dedicated terminal"? Should I use a different approach to debug this application? Do you have any suggestion on how can I reduce the number of hindrances in this *specific context*?

---

<sup>1</sup> The actual bug is that the UI, after a certain number of actions(and in a *completely deterministic* way), is not updated but waits for an extra keypress(that shouldn't be needed since I have set `halfdelay` mode precisely to avoid this). I want to know what the client is doing in that exact moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can separate gdb and program's output using `tty` gdb command. Here is detailed instruction how to do it from [Peter's gdb Tutorial](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/07-Debugging_Ncurses_Programs.php#ncurses):

Go to the first xterm and find its device file using either tty or who am i. This will be the xterm with GDB's I/O.:

```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/1
   $ who am i
   p        pts/1        May 26 12:44 (:0.0)
```

Go to the second xterm and find its device file. This will be the xterm with our program's I/O:

```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/4
```

Go back to the first xterm and start a debugging session. Set a breakpoint at Print_A_Character().

```
   $ gdb debugging_ncurses
   (gdb) break Print_A_Character 
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x80486fd: file debugging_ncurses.c, line 26.
   (gdb)
```

GDB's tty command instructs GDB to redirect the program's I/O to another terminal. The argument to tty is the device file of the terminal you wish the program I/O to go. In this case, I want the program's I/O to go to the second xterm, pts/4. If you're following along, use whatever device file you obtained in step 2:

```
   (gdb) tty /dev/pts/4
   (gdb)
```

Lastly, go to the second xterm (that contains the program's I/O) and tell the shell to sleep for a long time. This is so that anything we type in that window will be sure to go to our program rather than the shell. The amount of time is arbitrary, but pick a time that's longer than you suspect the debugging session will last. This tells the shell to "do nothing" for 100000 seconds:

```
   $ tty
   /dev/pts/4
   $ sleep 100000
```

Go back to the first xterm which is running GDB and debug to your heart's content. When you're done, you can go back to the program output window and slap it with a control-c to break out of the sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Run GDB in another terminal and attach to the running process you want to debug.  This should give your app and GDB their own terminals.  See http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/06-Debugging_A_Running_Process.php