# How to properly debug a python3.3 curses application using pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.3, curses

When using `pdb` to debug a curses application, the interactive debugger is useless, since `curses` messes up the terminal screen. Debugging post mortem works though, but that is a bit limited.

So what we probably need is having the debugger work in a terminal separately from the debuggee (the application that is being debugged).
Some alternatives which apply remote debugging (such as `xpdb`) appear either not to work with python 3.3 or give weird errors for other reasons.

So how can I use `pdb` in a different terminal, or in another proper way?

Comment: Relatex: [How to effectively debug a multi-threaded curses client-server application with gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304389/how-to-effectively-debug-a-multi-threaded-curses-client-server-application-with). The principles should be the same. Also you could use the `pdb` module instead and instantiate a [`Pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb) with different `stdin`/`stdout` files.

Comment: `pdb` appears not to have a `tty` command like `gdb` does.

Comment: Changing stdin/stdout to a separate terminal seems to work for `set_trace()`. However, several things don't work properly, such as completion, command history, etc.

Comment: Probably this is a missing feature. You should try to open a ticket on python's issues tracker, and maybe also in [`pdb-clone`](http://code.google.com/p/pdb-clone/) issues tracker.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue20061

Answer (score 0):

Use some debugger's functionalities  for attach to a running process. For instance you can try:

```
gdb python <pid>
```

See how here [Python Wiki DebuggingWithGdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb).

being  the pid of the process you want to debug. Also there is [WinPdb](http://winpdb.org/) that allows you to connect to a remote or local process. WinPdb is well documented and I think is your best option.

Comment: For me winpdb doesn't work for some reason. When I run `python3.3 /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py --debuggee script.py` it gives an error: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 13682, in __getsignal
    handler = g_signal_handlers.get(signum, g_signal_getsignal(signum))
ValueError: signal number out of range

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764082/cant-get-winpdb-working-with-python-3-3

Answer (score -1):

I've found that this bit of advice from the Python documentation helps:

> A common problem when debugging a curses application is to get your
>   terminal messed up when the application dies without restoring the
>   terminal to its previous state. In Python this commonly happens when
>   your code is buggy and raises an uncaught exception. Keys are no
>   longer echoed to the screen when you type them, for example, which
>   makes using the shell difficult. In Python you can avoid these
>   complications and make debugging much easier by importing the module
>   curses.wrapper. It supplies a wrapper() function that takes a
>   callable. It does the initializations described above, and also
>   initializes colors if color support is present. It then runs your
>   provided callable and finally deinitializes appropriately. The
>   callable is called inside a try-catch clause which catches exceptions,
>   performs curses deinitialization, and then passes the exception
>   upwards. Thus, your terminal won’t be left in a funny state on
>   exception.

Please see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) for info.

Comment: I already do that - you should always do that when writing a curses application. The usage of `curses.wrapper` is also the reason that post mortem debugging works as pointed out in the OP. However, debugging a running curses application on-the-fly, by using `set_trace` for instance, doesn't work, since the curses application has not been shut down.

Comment: `curses.wrapper()` is for recovering from a crash with the window settings restored. OP wants to use the pdb debugger with a curses app.

Comment: That's not what he is asking. The problem is not the state AFTER an error, the problem is the state during debugging