# winpdb not working with python 3.3

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, python-3.3, winpdb

I can't get rpdb2 to run with python 3.3, while that should be possible according to several sources.

```
$ rpdb2 -d myscript.py
A password should be set to secure debugger client-server communication.
Please type a password:x
Password has been set.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rpdb2", line 31, in <module>
    rpdb2.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 14470, in main
    StartServer(_rpdb2_args, fchdir, _rpdb2_pwd, fAllowUnencrypted, fAllowRemote, secret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 14212, in StartServer
    g_module_main = -1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 14212, in StartServer
    g_module_main = -1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 7324, in trace_dispatch_init
    self.__set_signal_handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 7286, in __set_signal_handler
    handler = signal.getsignal(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/rpdb2.py", line 13682, in __getsignal
    handler = g_signal_handlers.get(signum, g_signal_getsignal(signum))
ValueError: signal number out of range
```

The version of rpdb2 is `RPDB 2.4.8 - Tychod`.
I installed it by running `pip-3.3 install winpdb`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem today here is what i've done for it to work.
Still i'm not too sure if this is correct to do it this way.

From:

```py
def __getsignal(signum):
    handler = g_signal_handlers.get(signum, g_signal_getsignal(signum))
    return handler
```

To:

```py
def __getsignal(signum):
    try:
        # The problems come from the signum which was 0.
        g_signal_getsignal(signum)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    handler = g_signal_handlers.get(signum, g_signal_getsignal(signum))
    return handler
```

This function shall be at line **13681** or something like.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of a problem is the extended list of attributes in a `signal` module that was used by rpdb2 to list all signals. New python versions added attributes like `SIG_BLOCK, SIG_UNBLOCK, SIG_SETMASK`

So the filtering should be extended too (patch changes just one line):

```
--- rpdb2.py
+++ rpdb2.py
@@ -7278,11 +7278,11 @@
     def __set_signal_handler(self):
         """
         Set rpdb2 to wrap all signal handlers.
         """
         for key, value in list(vars(signal).items()):
-            if not key.startswith('SIG') or key in ['SIGRTMIN', 'SIGRTMAX'] or key.startswith('SIG_'):
+            if not key.startswith('SIG') or key in ['SIG_IGN', 'SIG_DFL', 'SIGRTMIN', 'SIGRTMAX']:
             continue

         handler = signal.getsignal(value)
         if handler in [signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL]:
             continue
```

Unfortunately there is no current official development or fork of winpdb, so by now this patch would be just stored on SO.